# Is it OK to have 'exit' statement in a subroutine of Open MP Critical region for Fortran?

Tags: fortran, openmp

There is a OpenMP `CRITICAL` region in my main code, like:

```
!$OMP CRITICAL
call one_subroutine
!$OMP END CRITICAL
```

Then in the subroutine, I have a if condition which contains `exit`, like:

```
if (x<a) exit
```

I want to know if this situation works since the `exit` statement is not allowed in most OMP regions, and how to change it if it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

The subroutine can contain anything you want. It may be subroutine written by somebody else and you may not even have the source code. It does not matter here.

Maybe there are some fine print exceptions, but an `exit` or even `return` statement is certainly completely fine inside that called subroutine.